# CurlException: 77: The one-time function was previously called and failed. Its error code is no longer available

Tags: php, facebook, api, curl

Have a Facebook app that is failing as of this morning with the following error:

> CurlException: 77: The one-time function was previously called and
>   failed. Its error code is no longer available

This is being thrown at the pint where I am trying to fetch the user's info:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

My code hasn't changed in weeks. Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Seems to be a Mozilla js error, not a Facebook error. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353899

Comment: It seems to be defined in mozilla:

#define PR_CALL_ONCE_ERROR                       (-5925L)

however that error is being triggered by the Facebook API call somehow. Still haven't figured out all the pieces yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what happened here, but it seems it was related to a package update based on the timings. These packages were updated:

```
Dec 12 09:25:48 Updated: php-common-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:48 Updated: nss-util-3.14-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:48 Updated: php-pdo-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:48 Updated: nss-softokn-freebl-3.14-5.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:48 Updated: nss-softokn-3.14-5.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:48 Updated: nss-sysinit-3.14-7.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:49 Updated: nss-3.14-7.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:49 Updated: php-cli-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:50 Updated: php-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:50 Updated: nss-tools-3.14-7.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:51 Updated: php-pgsql-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:51 Updated: php-mysql-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:51 Updated: php-gd-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:51 Updated: php-mbstring-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:51 Updated: php-mcrypt-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:51 Updated: php-pspell-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:51 Updated: php-xml-5.4.9-1.fc17.x86_64
Dec 12 09:25:54 Updated: tzdata-2012j-1.fc17.noarch
Dec 12 09:25:54 Updated: libgusb-0.1.4-1.fc17.x86_64
```

The fix was a simple reboot, so something was out of place.